# Bug, in Chrome, with draggable element which makes disappears many divs when I drop it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, draggable

I have a very strange problem that I can't solve.

I have an application being created with draggable divs.

Everything was working fine so far. But since a few hours, as soon as I drop a draggable div, most of the divs on my page disappear, even though they are not related to the element at all!

As soon as I resize my page, the divs reappear. It's as if it's a display bug. Moreover, this problem only happens on Chrome. No error message is displayed though.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't post relevant code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We are facing the same issue. It seems to be related to a Chromium update to version 106.0.5249.x (.62 and .91, at least, have the problem)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73972272/google-chrome-106-draggable-causing-elements-to-disappear

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1370030&sort=-modified%20-opened%20target&q=drag&can=1

Answer (score 1):

Google is aware if this problem and they fixed it in Chrome version 107, which is currently in Beta status. I was facing the same issue so I installed the Beta version and confirmed it is resolved. You can download the beta here:
https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/

I would also mention that this problem started with Chrome version 106, which is the latest stable version as of today.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I suspected it was a chrome bug but I couldn't find any info. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Until Chrome is fixed, I found this workaround which fixes the problem. Add this style to the draggable element:

background-position: 0;
transform: translate(0, 0);

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! It's perfect, I will create a temporary class until the bug will be fixed. Thank you

Comment: Drag still buggy in Chrome Version 112.0.5615.137. Fixed just with the transform property `transform: translateZ(0)`

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this is coming out soon.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1370030

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).