# Google Chrome 106 draggable causing elements to disappear

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, draggable

When using Drag & Drop elements most other elements contained in absolute positioned elements disappear from screen.

If I resize the window these elements reappear but will again disappear when begining to drag.

I'm experiencing this behavour in the latest version of Google Chrome (106 & Beta Version 107.0.5304.18) and now Edge.

I'm unsure if this is a bug (I would hope so) but it has broken most of my clients web apps!

**EDIT: I'm getting mixed reports about it working on Beta 107. The issue is still present for some users and not others.**

This snippet demonstrates the issue but the code below is all I'm using to replicate the issue.

```css
ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

div {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Example item</li>
  <li>Example item</li>
  <li>Example item</li>
  <li>Example item</li>
  <li>Example item</li>
</ul>
<div draggable="true">
  Please drag me
</div>
```

Are any of you experiencing these issues, does anyone have a work around for this or do you suspect this is a bug and we should hold out and hope for a fix?

Comment: Thanks @cloned for the edit, I didn't know about runnable code snippets!

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1370030&sort=-modified%20-opened%20target&q=drag&can=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is posted in the [Chromium issue thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1370030&sort=-modified%20-opened%20target&q=drag&can=1), you could add the following styles to the draggable element as a workaround/fix.

```
transform: translate(0, 0);
z-index: 0;
```

Comment: How would I know the date it is fixed?  we cannot make a workaround to publish a patch version to all our clients. Temporarily we said they can repaint the window resizing the browser, but what a shame .... Thank you Chromium

Comment: @Theo In the latest comment of that thread, it is stated that Stable 107 will be released on Oct 25, and this issue has been fixed in version 107.

Answer (score 0):

To apply as a global to all draggable elements in your app.

Use the following style rule (as mentioned in #C17 in a chromium Bug report)

```
[draggable="true"] {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    z-index: 0;
}
```